# Meteor - On page refresh, get user data in triggersEnter

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts, flow-router

The application I am building is designed so user's register with just an email address and password, but when they login, it is required that they then fill in a username and birthday.

I have created a route group using FlowRouter for authenticated users:

```
var authRoutes = FlowRouter.group({
    name: 'auth',
    triggersEnter: [function(context, redirect) {
        // Is the user logging in or already logged in?
        if(Meteor.loggingIn() || Meteor.userId()) {
            //They are, so track when user is available
            Tracker.autorun(function() {
                if(Meteor.user()) {
                    // User is available
                }
            });
        } else {
            // They are not
            FlowRouter.redirect('/login');
        }
    }],
});
```

However, this seems like the wrong way to go about this (having to track when the user is available in the route group). Is there a different way to achieve the same thing?